# Level curves of $|e^{1/z}|= s$ for $s \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: plotting, complex, regionplot

In order to find the behavior of a complex-valued function at an essential singularity, I want to plot $|e^{1/z}|= s$ for $s \in \mathbb{R}$, say for $s= 1, 1/2$. Following is the code but it doesn't show an output.

```
ContourPlot[{
  Abs[Exp[1/z]] == 1,
  Abs[Exp[1/z]] == 1/2}, 
{z, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}, 
ContourStyle -> {Blue, Red},
FrameLabel -> {"Re(z)", "Im(z)"},
PlotLegends -> {"|e^(1/z)| = 1", "|e^(1/z)| = 1/2"}
]
```

Any help in getting the desired output is much appreciated.

---

Edit : I tried the suggested answer but it still doesn't show an output. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit

For the old version (before 12.1) we can use

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
 ContourPlot[
  Abs[Exp[1/z]] == {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5} // Thread // 
   Evaluate, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ContourStyle -> Automatic]]
```

- For complex functions ,we using `ComplexContourPlot`.

```
ComplexContourPlot[
 Abs[Exp[1/z]] == {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5} // Thread // 
  Evaluate, {z, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}, ContourStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the prompt response. I've edited the question as I still didn't get an output.

Comment: @Eureka see the updated.

Comment: many thanks ! Will it be possible to put a label corresponding to each curve with the respective $s$ value ?

Comment: @Eureka  Maybe `Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
 ContourPlot[Abs[Exp[1/z]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5}, 
  ContourStyle -> ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], ContourLabels -> All, 
  ContourShading -> None]]`